# vmprof: Example config.ini file: configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError

Tags: python

I tried to follow the description [here](https://vmprof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vmprof.html#requirements) which says to create a `config.ini` file with the example content:

```
web-url = vmprof.com
web-auth = ffb7d4bee2d6436bbe97e4d191bf7d23f85dfeb2
period = 0.1
```

When I run this (via `python3 -m vmprof --config config.ini main.py`), I get the error:

```
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

I guess I should add some section header (like `[header]`?). But what header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out by playing around. It must be the `[global]` section.

Comment: Even with this, I'm still getting an error:server rejected meta data. status: 400, msg: '["could not extract meta data for .... exception: [Errno 111] Connection refused"]'

Comment: @Batman0730: This sounds like another error. You should ask a separate question for it. If you think it is related to this one here, put a link.